# How can I find a decimal and binary from a string?

Tags: algorithm

I have input such as `5 2 113221101000101`（'5' is quinary and '2' is binary）I have a `number` quinary and binary but they are joined without space（'113221101000101'）.

So my question is how can I find the exact `number` through the `5 2 113221101000101`（the number is `837`）

I add some examples:

`5 2 113221101000101`  the number is `837`

`13 7 1016` the number is `13`

`4 12 2222248A` the number is `682`

`A` to `F` represents the nums `10` to `15`

Comment: `2` isn't a valid binary digit. And without knowing more of the requirements or specifications, or the full assignment/exercise text, it's going to be *really* hard to help you. Please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And of course please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt to show us.

Comment: @Dukeling: Looks like it's a simple concatenation of the base 5 and binary digits for the same number: (837 is `11322` in base 5 and `1101000101` in base 2). Given that, it should be possible to separate.

Comment: @MarkDickinson you are right

Comment: Do you know the "number" beforehand? Is it part of the input? Otherwise it's in most cases impossible to separate the third input into the two parts.

Comment: I think the `5 2` means "the following is a concatenation of a base 5 and a base 2 number", and then the number.

Comment: Oh, I think I get it, from the second example - it's the same number concatenated in the two bases (10 is 13 in base 13, 16 is 13 in base 7).

Comment: I hope you thought about the problem ?homework? yourself, before trying to get a solution here.

Answer (score 1):

You should realize that you can decode a string either from right to left or from left to right. The algorithms are different but straight forward.

You can decode the string starting from the left using the first base and from the right using the other base.

Always decode an other character based on which value is smaller (the one decoded starting right or the one starting left).
If both values are equal, decode one more digit for the smaller base.

When both decodings have consumed all characters of the string, they should have produced the same value which is your result.

Example:

```
5 2 113221101000101 the number is 837

1-------------1             
1 base 5      1 base 2  1=1 -> decode base 2

1------------01
1 base 5      1 base 2  1=1 -> decode base 2

1-----------101
1 base 5      5 base 2  1<5 -> decode base 5

11----------101
6 base 5      5 base 2  6>5 -> decode base 2

11---------0101    
6 base 5      5 base 2  6>5 -> decode base 2

11---------0101    
6 base 5      5 base 2  6>5 -> decode base 2

11--------00101
6 base 5      5 base 2  6>5 -> decode base 2

11-------000101 
6 base 5      5 base 2  6>5 -> decode base 2

11------1000101
6 base 5     69 base 2  6<69 -> decode base 5

113-----1000101    
33 base 5    69 base 2  33<69 -> decode base 5

1132----1000101
167 base 5   69 base 2  167>69 -> decode base 2

1132---01000101
167 base 5   69 base 2  167>69 -> decode base 2

1132--101000101
167 base 5  325 base 2  167<325 -> decode base 5

11322-101000101 
837 base 5  325 base 2  837>325 -> decode base 2

113221101000101    
837 base 5  837 base 2  finished
```

Answer (score 0):

You can work by "brute force", i.e. perform all conversions from the two given bases, with all possible splits, and stop at equality (unless several solutions are possible).

In fact you can make this in a relatively efficient way by

- converting the whole string from base A, from left to right, keeping all intermediate results;
- converting again left-to-right from base B and comparing to the complementary base-A decodings.

---

Note that the number of digits in both representations can be estimated, as they are inversely proportional to the logarithm of the base. With some care it is probably possible to predict the number of digits to within one unit, and this can slightly shorten the conversion workload.

For instance, the first number yields the length estimates 4.52 and 10.48, which hints the decomposition 5/10.

Comment: Estimating the length of both encodings can be tricky, because you can add as many `0`s between them as you want without changing the result.

Comment: @MrSmith42: there is not reason to prepend leading zeroes. In the given examples, there are none.

Comment: You are right but zeros are not ruled out in the problem description. I only wanted to point out that this might be a problem for estimating the number of digits for each encoding.

Comment: @MrSmith42: you artificially introduce a difficulty where there is none.

Comment: From my point of view, by assuming there are no such zeros you make an assumption not backed up by the problem description. Never the less I think it is justified to make the comment that this could be a problem.